# Теоретический вопрос про getter

Tags: getter, php

Допустимо чтобы геттер проверял, присвоено ли значение свойству? Или проверку лучше вынести в отдельный метод, например checkName()

```
Class Myclass
{
    private $_name;

    public function setName($value)
    {
        $this->_name = $value;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        if (isset($this->_name)) {
            return $this->_name;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Имя не определено');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

для таких целей используются [методы-перехватчики](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php)

Comment: __get() не работает, т.к. доступ к переменной осуществляется через public метод.

Comment: Вопрос скорее философский, а не теоретический :)

Comment: @DDD, чтобы юзать __get(), не нужно создавать никаких свойств. Когда идет обращение к несуществующему свойству, автоматически срабатывает метод __get, которому передается имя свойства. А уж по этому имени можно вытаскивать значения, например, из заранее напичканного массива по ключу, который равен этому несуществующему свойству

Comment: Дело в том, что свойство у нас создано. И мы можем получить его значение через метод класса. Мне нужно проверить, присвоено ли значение свойству или нет. Я вижу два пути, проверять в геттере или вынести проверку в отдельный метод.
p.s. Вопрос сформулировал по-другому, чтобы было более понятно.

Comment: @DDD, та и так пойдет. только юзай throw в связке с try-catch